# Docusign multiple signers for one signature line

Tags: docusignapi

We have a document that requires two signatures.  The first signature is to a specific individual, but the second signature can be signed by three or four managers for approval.  Only one signature from any of those managers is needed, so the first to sign is enough for the document to be considered approved.

So we wish to use the api to make a request of any of these three or four managers to approve the document.  Once any ONE of them signs, the document is complete.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Dennis

Comment: Are the managers using a shared email address or they have their own email addresses?  If they are sharing a common group email for these requests then you can use the `Any Signer` feature for the second recipient...

Answer (score 0):

If your recipients start the signing process from the email notification from Docusign (aka "Remote signing"), I agree that Any Signer is a good option to consider. The documentation for this approach was recently updated at: [DocuSign Downloads](https://www.docusign.com/support/downloads)

[Direct link to the PDF](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/quick-start-using-the-any-signer-option.pdf)

Update: There was recently a DocuSign blog post on this feature as well: https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-send-a-document-to-multiple-parties-with-the-docusign-any-signer-feature

Comment: Ok, I've found the feature, but not seeing it from the API.  We can ask that the company use a common group email if that's what is necessary.