# Adding a secondary recipient to sign a document

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign REST services and currently passing in the recipients required to sign the document from two People columns in a SharePoint document library. The client would now like to have it that they have secondary signers, e.g. the original users could sign but if they are not available their assistant must do so. What would be the best solution for this?

I noticed mention of something similar here:
[Docusign multiple signers for one signature line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537975/docusign-multiple-signers-for-one-signature-line)

They want this to happen at run time though, so the email addresses get sent on the original request to create the envelope and this solution above speaks more to the concept of creating them via the DocuSign interface which is not ideal for them. Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please "check" the answer that best helps with your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

Do the assistants sign as themselves or on behalf of the original signer? I'm making some assumptions here, but most assistants would have access to their boss' emails, so presumably they'd have access to the DocuSign notifications that comes though. In that case, the assistant could simply sign as the original signer by clicking through to the envelope from the email. While this is usually a bit of an eyebrow raising move in terms of security, the reality is that many partners in law firms already delegate their authority to their PAs to sign on their behalf, and today these PAs have copies of all their bosses' signature images to place on documents.

A slightly better move, if the requirement is for the assistant to sign under their own name, is to go into the envelope from their boss' email and reassign the envelope to themselves. Then they will receive an email and they can sign under their own name and all of this will show in the audit trail.

Either way there isn't anything you need to do from an API perspective apart from ensuring the right features are turned on to allow signers to reassign.

The other option is using Signing Groups, but the groups need to be set up beforehand in the DocuSign account and your API call will enter the signing group ID (under the "signingGroupId" parameter) instead of the recipient name and email. This means either the boss or their assistant could sign if they are in the same signing group, but does not enforce one over the other.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jenny